# Extracting text between two characters in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to extract the text between two characters using t-sql.  I have been able to write it where it pulls the information close to what I want, but for some reason I am not getting what i am expecting(suprise, suprise).  Could really use alittle help refining it.  I am trying to extract part of the table name that is located between two [ ].  An example of the column data is as follows(this is a table that records all changes made to the database so the column text is basically SQL statements):

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLENAME].[MYTABLE] ADD
[VIP_CUSTOMER] [int] NULL
```

I am trying to extract part of the table name, in this example I just want 'MYTABLE'

Right now I am using:

```
select  SUBSTRING(db.Event_Text, CHARINDEX('.', db.Event_Text) + 2, (CHARINDEX(']', db.Event_Text)) - CHARINDEX('', db.Event_Text) + Len(']')) as OBJName
FROM DBA_AUDIT_EVENT DB
WHERE DATABASE_NAME = 'XYZ'
```

But when I use this, I don't always get the results needed.  Sometimes I get 'MYTABLE] ADD' and sometimes I get the part of the name I want, and sometimes depending on the length of the tablename I only get part the first part of the name with part of the name cut off at the end.  Is there anyway to get this right, or is there a better way of writing it?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: One problem I see is CHARINDEX('', db.Event_Text) which will return zero every time.  I'm assuming that's not what you intended.

Comment: Is that something you could add when capture those event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long, but here's a formula using the brackets:

```
Declare @text varchar(200);
Select @text='ALTER TABLE [TABLENAME].[MYTABLE] ADD [VIP_CUSTOMER] [int] NULL';
Select SUBSTRING(@text, 
                 CHARINDEX('[', @text, CHARINDEX('[', @text) + 1 ) +1, 
                 CHARINDEX(']', @text, CHARINDEX('[', @text, CHARINDEX('[', @text) + 1 ) ) -
                    CHARINDEX('[', @text, CHARINDEX('[', @text) + 1 ) - 1 );
```

Replace @text with your column name.

Comment: Thanks Tony, this answer worked perfectly.  Appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

this is a pretty ugly way to get the length, but I've used something like this before:

```
select  SUBSTRING(db.Event_Text, 
    CHARINDEX('.', db.Event_Text) + 2,  
    charindex('] ADD',db.Event_Text) - CHARINDEX('.',db.Event_Text)-2))
```

Give it a try, it may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
select SUBSTRING(db.Event_Text, CHARINDEX('.', db.Event_Text) + 2
, CHARINDEX(']', db.Event_Text) - 2) as OBJName
FROM DBA_AUDIT_EVENT DB
WHERE DATABASE_NAME = 'XYZ'
```

Comment: This basically caused the same problems as my statement.  Still gave incomplete names or more than needed.